# How do I use Runge-Kutta Iterative method to produce a table of values for a function?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems, runge-kutta-methods

> Describe how the fourth-order Runge-Kutta method can be used to produce a table of values for the function
>
> $$f(x)=\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\ \mathsf dx$$
>
> at $100$ equally spaced points in the unit interval.

Answer:
Find an appropriate initial-value problem whose solution is f. Solve df =e^{−x^2}, f(0)=0.

The answer is a little confusing and can anyone write out the full answer? I suppose my question is how after i take the derivative and transform the intergral equation into a differential equation with initial value, how do i know the step size h? n how do i know the initial value? I know what runge kutta 4th order is The runge kutta method is

$$k_1 = f(t_0,x(t_0))$$
$$k_2 = f(t_0+h/2,x(t_0)+k_1/2)$$
$$k_3 = f(t_0+h/2,x(t_0)hk_2/2)$$
$$k_4 = f(t_0+h,x(t_0)+k_3)$$
Then
$$x(t_0+h)= x(t_0) + h\frac{k_1+2k_2+2k_3+k_4}{6}$$

Comment: Look for Simpson integration, no need to transform a simple quadrature into a differential equation.

Answer (score 2):

Focus less on symbols and concentrate on the properties of the objects. A change of symbols might clarify matters. Let $y : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by
$$ y(t) = \int_0^t e^{-s^2}ds.$$
Then $y(0) = 0$ and
$$ y'(t) = e^{-t^2}.$$
If we define $f : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ as follows,
$$ f(t,y) = e^{-t^2},$$
where there is no explicit dependence on the second variable, then we can write
$$ y'(t) = f(t,y).$$
You are now in a position to apply, say, the classical fourth order Runge-Kutta method.